# Why do not you run low in sleep mode?

Tags: sim800

-1
down vote
I work with the Sim808 module I'm going to Sleep, but it does not go down !!!!! With the Sim800, I'm going to sleep! I use the AT + CSCLK = 1 command Streaming on SIM808 Before 26 mAh later 26 mA Streaming on SIM800 Before 16 mAh later 1 mA

Meanwhile, in both modules after the SLEEP, the serial communication is dropped, indicating that the command is sent correctly to the module. So why does not crack in SMI808.

Please give me guidance. Thank you

Hello
In datasheet
If you use sleep mode, the power consumption is low.
But for my module, the circuit current does not change. !!!
Steps on the module:
1-circuit current of 26 mA
2. Sending code AT + CSCLK = 1
3-Serial connection disconnected.
4. In fact, the module is in sleep mode.
5-Circuit current of 26 mA

Why before and after sleep, the current circuit is 26 mAh !!!!! ????
According to the data, the circuit must be 1 mAh. !!!!

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - you did not show any.. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Your text is most unclear. I really don't get where your problem is and why you downvote or whatever.

Comment: Hello
In datasheet
If you use sleep mode, the power consumption is low.
But for my module, the circuit current does not change. !!!
Steps on the module:
1-circuit current of 26 mA
2. Sending code AT + CSCLK = 1
3-Serial connection disconnected.
4. In fact, the module is in sleep mode.
5-Circuit current of 26 mA

Why before and after sleep, the current circuit is 26 mAh !!!!! ????
According to the data, the circuit must be 1 mAh. !!!!